# What is the proper way to implement previous page navigation in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, paging, cql3, bigdata

I'm playing with cassandra for some time and the one thing I'm less satisfied with is the previous page pagination.

As far as I can understand cassandra has auto paging support. All I have to give is PageSize and the PageState and its returning the next set of rows.

I have no problem with the "Next" page link since everytime I query cassandra it returns the next PageState.

However I have no idea what is the right way to implement previous page link. Since my project is a web app, its very important to have previous page link.

At the moment the only way I can go back to previous page is by storing all past PageStates in Sessions.

This is fine for a few page site. But the reason I choose cassandra is for big data. I don't wanna keep track of all past PageStates.

I don't want to expose the page state in browser either because of security reasons. What is the proper way to implement paging with proper previous page link?

Comment: what is the primary key of your table ?

Comment: clustering key can be used to pagination

Comment: @AshrafulIslam When I use clustering column for pagination, the data is not ordered correctly. I may have to use the token function but i still prefer the cassandra auto paging. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the following [Backward paging in cassandra c# driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922386/backward-paging-in-cassandra-c-sharp-driver).
We have implemented similar thing with encryption though.

Comment: You mean you encrypted the page state?

Comment: Yes. As it was pretty long... We did that for SOLR deep pagination via Datastax Cassandra driver as well.